# Repeating a procedure a user specified amount of times

Tags: delphi

I have numerous procedures which dynamically create a TButton when the user clicks a button. The following code is an example of this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

 begin

 if not Assigned(FSeatButton) then begin

   FSeatButton := TButton.Create(self);
   FSeatButton.Parent := self;
   FSeatButton.Left := 100;
   FSeatButton.Top := 100;
   FSeatButton.Width := 62;
   FSeatButton.Height := 25;
   FSeatButton.Caption := ('Seat');
   FSeatButton.OnMouseDown := ButtonMouseDown;
   FSeatButton.OnMouseMove := ButtonMouseMove;
   FSeatButton.OnMouseUp := ButtonMouseUp;

 end;
 end;
```

This creates a Tbutton which the user can then drag around through the bottom 3 procedures. I need this procedure to repeat every time a user clicks button2 but if I use a for/repeat loop id have to specify when to end it, but i don't know how many Buttons the user will need to generate.

Also (This could be an idea for another question), how would i save each button created with its own ID as such E.G Button1, Button2... ButtonN. I'm guessing I'd need some sort of variable that increases every time the user clicks the button and it is somehow included in the name E.G ButtonI

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it only allows one button to be created, once created it doesn't work again

Comment: Just remove the 'if not assigned' bit of it and set the button name. Just make sure the name is unique, e.g. by incrementing a variable and appending it to 'Seat'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to keep track of all the buttons that have been added. Use a container to do so:

In the type declaration add a container:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

....

FButtons: TList<TButton>;
```

Instantiate it in the form's constructor, and destroy it in the destructor. Or use the `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events if you prefer.

Then when you create the button, add it to the list:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Button: TButton;
begin
  Button := TButton.Create(self);
  Button.Parent := Self;
  Button.Left := 100;
  // etc.

  FButtons.Add(Button);
end;
```

If you don't need to refer to the buttons after creating them then you don't need the list and you can just do this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Button: TButton;
begin
  Button := TButton.Create(self);
  Button.Parent := Self;
  Button.Left := 100;
end;
```

Comment: upvoted for TList, which is better than a dynamic array of TButton imo

Comment: @davidheffernan could you explain what you mean by constructor and deconstructor or provide an example, fairly new to this. Also, when I put the tlist in type it said undeclared identifier, am I missing something?

Comment: Start here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Constructors  and I've added to the answer the `uses` that you need for `TList<T>`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok so I've read through it and different examples and what I don't understand is they create the object in the constructor whilst i have this procedure that does it for me. Do I need to remove the procedure and then in the constructor do Button2Click.OnClick and copy the procedure code into the constructor?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no i mean the example you provided and others online,http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Constructors
They create the object in the constructor i think

Comment: This feels like it is outside the scope of this question. This is a much more basic and fundamental issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how can i fix this issue? I have no knowledge of constructors but that site doesn't explain them in a way i can understand

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to progress if you don't know how to write constructors. Which text book are you using to learn the language?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I dont have one, is there one you recommend?

Comment: I am the wrong person to ask that. I have been a Delphi programmer for 20 years. I've no idea how a beginner would learn.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `FSeatButton : array of TButton;`
That way you have an unique instance of the added buttons and can name them in consecutive order.

Every time `Button2` is clicked add a new button to the array:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  len: Integer;
begin
  len := Length(FSeatButton);
  SetLength(FSeatButton,len+1);
  FSeatButton[len] := TButton.Create(self);
  FSeatButton[len].Name := 'SeatButton'+IntToStr(len);
  etc...
end;
```

Comment: can you explain why you feel this is better?

Comment: A `TList` is a class encapsuling a dynamic array and adding many methods to handle the internal elements of the array. In your case, it only adds extra coding to manage this class (construction/destruction), since you have no use of all the extra the `TList` has to offer. A dynamic array is all you need, you only add a new item and can easily manage each item afterwards if there is need for that. And a dynamic array has a reference counting system built-in, which means that you don't need to manage the life-time of it. When the array goes out of scope, it will be disposed of automatically.

Comment: So at a later point I will be able to reference the objects in the array and save their name, location etc

Comment: Yes, exactly that.